# Issuing In-App Facebook Credits Refund

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits, credits

I understand that a user can create a dispute via the Facebook tools for Reporting an app which goes through the Facebook channels for getting a refund (for item not received or whatever else). In our app we want a 14-day money back guarantee policy if the user is not satified with the virtual goods they have purchased.  My question is, is this possible to implement with the Facebook API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph API call used to refund order:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ORDER_ID?access_token=TOKEN&
     status=refunded&message=refunding%20order&method=post
```

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/disputes/

See **In-App Dispute Flow** as well as **How Developers Resolve User Disputes** for information on how to accomplish this.